# smo.application.enumAvailableSqlServers not returning available SQL Servers

Tags: c#, sql, smo

I am trying to use the following c# code to display available sql servers in a listbox:

```
DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   listBox3.Items.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
}
```

However, the list box remains empty, and when I debug, I find that `dt.Rows` is equal to zero, event though I have a server with SQL Server 2012 Express.

Any ideas?

Comment: Relevant reading: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2008/02/10/programatically-listing-sql-servers.aspx Also, you need to consistent -- you claimed in your last question (where it was suggested you use SMO) to be using SQLEXPRESS 2010. Which is it?

Comment: yeah sorry for the confusion, it is 2012.

Comment: and no, no exceptions. It executes the code but it never enters the foreach statement.

Comment: Roger, it makes no sense to say "it just never enters for for loop". Unless that smo call makes your application exit immediately, there must be an exception. And it's very likely an exception that causes an exit! What happens when you single step in the debugger? Does the smo call ever return?

Answer (score 0):

One possiblity is that you do not have the [SQL Server Browser Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510203(v=sql.110).aspx) running. According to the MSDN page:

> SQL Server Browser contributes to the following actions:
>
> - Browsing a list of available servers
> - Connecting to the correct server instance
> - Connecting to dedicated administrator connection (DAC) endpoints

Another thing I've done in the case of a 32-bit app asking for a list of local SQL instances and coming up empty because there were only 64-bit instances on the machine was to spelunk the registry:

```
 List<string> servers = new List<string>();

 // Get servers from the registry (if any)
 RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
 key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
 object installedInstances = null;
 if (key != null) { installedInstances = key.GetValue("InstalledInstances"); }
 List<string> instances = null;
 if (installedInstances != null) { instances = ((string[])installedInstances).ToList(); }
 if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) {
    /* The above registry check gets routed to the syswow portion of 
     * the registry because we're running in a 32-bit app. Need 
     * to get the 64-bit registry value(s) */
    key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
    key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
    installedInstances = null;
    if (key != null) { installedInstances = key.GetValue("InstalledInstances"); }
    string[] moreInstances = null;
    if (installedInstances != null) { 
       moreInstances = (string[])installedInstances;
       if (instances == null) {
          instances = moreInstances.ToList();
       } else {
          instances.AddRange(moreInstances);
       }
    }
 }
 foreach (string item in instances) {
    string name = System.Environment.MachineName;
    if (item != "MSSQLSERVER") { name += @"\" + item; }
    if (!servers.Contains(name.ToUpper())) { servers.Add(name.ToUpper()); }
 }
```

Comment: The correct key name for Server 2008 and Windows 8 is "Instance Names"